# How to keep an Ursina window always on top?

Tags: python, window, always-on-top

I am using the Python `Ursina` game engine to make a 3D character. I want to keep the window always on top, like a picture-in-picture video. How would I do this, currently my code is as follows...

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

cube = Entity(model='cube')

def update():
    cube.rotation_y += 1

app.run()
```

The code runs fine, but it is always behind the other windows I open. Any advice or solutions out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use win32 gui

```
import win32gui
def windowEnumerationHandler(hwnd, top_windows):
    top_windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = []
    top_windows = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, top_windows)
    for i in top_windows:
        if "window name" in i[1].lower():
            print i
            win32gui.ShowWindow(i[0],5)
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(i[0])
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a window stay on top unless minimized by initiating `window.always_on_top = True` before you initialize the `app = Ursina()` function like this:

```
from ursina import * 
window.always_on_top = True
app = Urinsa()
app.run()
```

other functions for the window that don't seem to work may only work if it is put before "app = Ursina()".